# Prevent Other Apps from Getting My App's Package Name and Name

Tags: android, security, android-package-managers

I have seen some other apps who are getting my app's package name. So I want to prevent them from getting my app's package name and name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is not possible.  There is no way to exclude your app from package manager listings.

However, as of Android 11, there have been [changes to package visibility for apps targeting Android 11](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility).  With these changes, if your app doesn't declare any intent filters or content provider authorities, then the set of apps targeting Android 11 that can get your application's package info would be restricted (to, mostly, apps that have the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission or that specifically list your app in their manifest).

Comment: Could You Please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569251/android-11-restrict-specific-app-from-getting-my-apps-package-name