# Android 11 Restrict specific app from Getting My App's Package Name

Tags: android, package, visibility, android-11

I have Noticed some other apps who are getting my app's package name. So I want to prevent them from getting my app's package name and name.

Answer (score 1):

thats not possible. till Android 10 any app can list all installed packages. Android 11 introduced some changes in [packages visibility](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9) and by default your app/package isn't "visible" for other common apps, BUT since then we have new permission: `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`. so there is no reliable way for hiding your app, as any 3rd-party may declare and obtain this perm and you can't prevent that...